# Can Visual Studio always open ASP.NET pages in Source view, not Design view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

Anyone know how to tell Visual Studio 2008 to always open up ASP.NET pages in "Source" mode, not "Design" mode?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Tools → Options → Web Forms Designer → Start pages in "Source view".

In VS < 2015 it was called HTML Designer.

For other extensions you can define specific behaviour by right clicking on a file and selecting `Open With`. This allows you to set once off or default behaviour for opening more esoteric file types.

For example, I use the [Sandcastle Help File Builder](http://www.codeplex.com/SHFB), so have `.shfbproj` extensions loading up the SHFB GUI, but you could also load it up as plain XML (or whatever).

Comment: Thanks.  I searched all over the place in VS and in Google before posting this question, and came up empty handed.  Your reply came in seconds ahead, so I'll mark it as the answer.

Comment: Cheers.  FWIW, I like the way Eclipse allows you to filter by keyword search in options. That would be useful in Visual Studio because I think we all have problems finding the right options sometimes :)

Comment: In VS2015 its called "Web Forms Designer" not "HTML designer"

Comment: Thank you, please feel free to edit my answer, assuming you have enough rights to do so.

Answer (score 6):

Yep, go to Tools -> Options -> HTML Designer -> General and select the "Start pages in Source View" option